# ArgumentNullException when indexing IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I have SocialEvents.BusinessLogic project that containes class EventsHelper

```
public class EventsHelper
{
    IRepository repo;

    public EventsHelper(IRepository repository)
    {
        repo = repository;          
    }
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents()
    {
        return repo.Events;
    }   
}
```

In my MVC project SocialEvents I have HomeController with Index action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static EventsHelper eventsHelper = new EventsHelper(new Repository());

    public ActionResult Index()
    {                        
        return View(eventsHelper);
    }
}
```

In Index view I am getting events

```
@{ var eventsList = Model.GetEvents();}
```

And later trying to index them

```
@if (eventsList != null)
{
    foreach (var _event in eventsList)
    {
        <h3>@_event.Title</h3>
    }                            
}
```

But I'm getting ArgumentNullException in foreach

The exception arise in `System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate)` Parameter name `source`

[Control values when running step-through debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzJLm.png)

I don't understand why this exception arise if IEnumerable object is not null and how to fix it

`Repository` class uses EntityFramework DbContext class `SocialEventsContext`

Repository

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly SocialEventsContext context = new SocialEventsContext();

    public IEnumerable<Event> Events
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Events;
        }
    }
    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
    public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

SocialEventsContext

```
public class SocialEventsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

[And in my localDb I actually have data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pz3.png)

StackTrace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +4396142
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in E:\Documents\Practice\SocialEvents\SocialEvents\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:50
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What's in repo.Events? you're using IEnumarable, so there's probably deffered execution here...

Comment: @OfirW I updated my question

Comment: Might you in fact have a IQueryable returned? Try adding ToList() on the end of the repo call.

Comment: @ste-fu like that `return repo.Events.ToList();`?

Comment: Yeah. Make sure that the query is executed against thw db.

Comment: @ste-fu it didn't work. I'm getting the same result

Comment: @EgorManevich Post the code of the repository

Comment: @OfirW I updated the question

Comment: @EgorManevich Can you post the entire exception including the stackTrace?

Comment: @OfirW ok, updated

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of the indexed loop, you're creating many deferred collections here, or consume it into a list before the loop at least.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks, I changed `for` to `foreach`, but this didn't solve the problem

Comment: I didn't think it would, but in my book I have one rule when it comes to software with a bug, if you can't fix the bug at least make it bug out quicker :) Judging by your stack trace it seems the actual collection returned was `null`. You need to debug.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understand, thanks, but refer to control values from step-through debugging collection is not null

Comment: The Stack Trace disagrees with you.

Comment: 1. On which line exactly do you get the exception? 2. Can you change the IEnumarable of GetEvents to List? 3. Is it possible that one of the events in the collection is null? and then youre failing on this:   <h3>@_event.Title</h3>

Answer (score 0):

Add property to your model class which will fill in controller and than pass that model to view.

**Model**

```
public class EventsHelper
    {
        IRepository repo;

        public EventsHelper(IRepository repository)
        {
            repo = repository;          
        }
        public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents()
        {
            return repo.Events;
        }  

      public List<Event> eventList {get; set;}
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static EventsHelper eventsHelper = new EventsHelper(new Repository());

    public ActionResult Index()
    {             
        eventsHelper.eventList = eventsHelper.GetEvents();
        return View(eventsHelper);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{ var eventsList = Model.eventList }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. The same exception at the same line

Comment: what exception you getting?

Comment: did you add **@Model.namespace.EventsHelper** in your view page? if no than it will not work paste your view here to identify the actual problem

Comment: I'm getting the same ArgumentNullException. Yes, I did add proper model path in my view